# How to style and add more fields to the bubble in a gmap field?

Tags: 7, theming, google-maps

I'm using gmap field, it displays only 1 bubble at the same time. If I click on bubble it displays title.

[image]

How can I customize it? I need to style it and add more fields to it.

I know how to do it using view (than I can do template for it), however in this case I have only gmap field that display itself.

I want to get this result:

[image]

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I used your solution and it worked, however due to current setup I went with solution where I used view (with context filter) + gmap format. There it is possible to set template for your bubble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [Comparison of mapping modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1704948):

> GMap is considered a legacy module.

So maybe you want to have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it. That project page also includes various screenshots.